# Скрипт для googl app script работал и ни с того перестал работать

Tags: javascript

Всем привет, такой вопрос писал скрипт наверное ещё года 2 назад, всё прекрасно работал и тут вдруго перестал и выдает ошибку

Exception: Invalid argument
myFunction  @ Копирка.gs:15

Сам скрипт предназначался для того что-бы копировать 1 табличку и вставлять ссылку на неё в другую, с копирыванием доступов всех пользователей дальше сам скрипт:

```
function myFunction() {
  fileId = '**ССЫЛКА НА КОПИРУЕММЫЙ ФАЙЛ**'; 
  var file = DriveApp.getFileById(fileId);
  var copyFile =  file.makeCopy("Таблица версия 6.1");
  var url = copyFile.getUrl();
  
  access     = file.getSharingAccess();
  permission = file.getSharingPermission();
  viewers    = file.getViewers();      
  editors    = file.getEditors();

  copyFile.setSharing(file.getSharingAccess(), file.getSharingPermission());

  for (var v=0; v < viewers.length; v++) {
    copyFile.addViewer(viewers[v]);
    }
  
  for (var ed=0; ed < editors.length; ed++) { 
    copyFile.addEditor(editors[ed]);
  }

  var SpreadsheetID = "**ССЫЛКА НА РЕЕСТ ТАБЛИЧЕК**";
  var SheetName = "Лист1";  

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(SpreadsheetID)
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(SheetName);
  
  var lastRow = parseInt(sheet.getLastRow())+1;
  console.log('B'+lastRow);
  sheet.getRange('B'+lastRow).setValue(url);
}
```

Comment: [как задать хороший вопрос](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Вы, возможно, исправили опечатку в имени листа: РЕЕСТ -> РЕЕСТР.  Если так, исправьте скрипт тоже.